# Venn Diagrams and Patterns

Tags: diagrams, pattern, venn-diagrams

As a teacher, I really appreciate the **venndiagram usepackage** with its functionality. Is there a way to fill the sets with patterns instead of a solid color (for better printing)? Something along the lines of `\begin{venndiagram2sets}[shade={pattern=horizontal lines}]`, or `\begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={pattern=horizontal lines}]`?

A working example without pattern fills follows. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[shade=orange,tikzoptions={red}]
   \fillA
\end{venndiagram2sets}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you look into the documentation of the venndiagram package, you will recognize that the fills are done with a command `\path[fill=\@venn@shade] ...`, where `=\@venn@shade` is the color that you specify with `shade=...` (orange in your example),The IMHO simplest way to do what you want is to copy the `venndiagram.sty` file to a new file in which you replace all ``\path[fill=\@venn@shade] ` by `\path[\@venn@shade]` and then do  `\begin{venndiagram2sets}[pattern=north east lines,tikzoptions={red}]` after loading your own package. Or send a request to the package author.

Comment: Thanks, really nice idea. I tried it in different variations (also changing the initial definition of `\newcommand*{\@venn@shade}{lightgray}` to `\newcommand*{\@venn@shade}{pattern=north east lines}`, however no luck so far. I'll keep trying, because I really like the idea.

Comment: This is because now you are effectively saying `fill={pattern=north east lines}`. The issue is to get rid of the hardcoded `fill=` and I think LoopSpace made a brilliant suggestion to accomplish that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with marmot's comment that the best option is to make the package more flexible (my suggestion would be to replace `fill=\@venn@shade` with something like `every venn region/.try`).  In the meantime, here's a fix that uses a scope to add extra options to the path.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446941/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[shade={},tikzoptions={red}]
\begin{scope}[every path/.append style={pattern=north east lines}]
\fillA
\end{scope}
\end{venndiagram2sets}

\end{document}
```

The `shade={}` is important.  It enables filling (since `shade=<colour>` becomes `fill=<colour>` in the code) but doesn't specify a colour.  The point here is that the `every path` style is examined *first* so putting `shade=<actual colour>` would override the pattern, while `shade=none` would disable it.  Only `shade={}` enables the pattern without overwriting it.

[image: patterned venn diagram]

---

*Update 2018-08-22*

Dealing with intersection regions turns out to be a bit tricky due to how clipping works.  The following is definitely in the region of *a bit of a hack*, but it does seem to work.  It appends some code to the `clip` command which removes the options and turns off any other options.  I *think* this deals with everything that can go bad with passing options to a clipping path.

I've also add a helper command that wraps a venn diagram command in a scope so that this technique works.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446941/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
%

\newcommand*\wrapscope[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname o#1\endcsname[1][]{%
    \begin{scope}[##1]
    \csname #1\endcsname
    \end{scope}
  }%
}%

\wrapscope{fillA}
\wrapscope{fillACapB}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  clip/.append code={%
    \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty
    \tikz@addmode\tikz@mode@fillfalse%
    \tikz@addmode\tikz@mode@drawfalse%
    \tikz@addmode\tikz@mode@doublefalse%
    \tikz@addmode\tikz@mode@boundaryfalse%
    \tikz@addmode\tikz@mode@fade@pathfalse%
    \tikz@addmode\tikz@mode@fade@scopefalse%
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[shade={},tikzoptions={red}]
%\ofillA[every path/.append style={pattern=north east lines}]
\ofillACapB[every path/.append style={pattern=north east lines}]
\end{venndiagram2sets}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! The fix worked perfectly for me. Do you see any problems to define a new environment including the scope fix? So far this seems to work perfectly for me.

Comment: I would define a new command based on `\fillA` that included the scope since it should really only apply to that command (I can envision wanting different patterns on different parts of the same diagram).  Something like `\newcommand*\ofillA[1][]{\scope[#1]\fillA\endscope}`.

Comment: That's a really cool solution!

Comment: @Loop Space Thanks again, nice solution! Hopefully last question: This works well for many commands, but not so for e.g. `\fillACapB`. It seems that the clipping  is the problem there. Any possible solution to that?

Comment: @Manuel That was tricky!  I want to put a disclaimer on this code - I don't know if it will break something else.  So use with caution!

Comment: If anyone wants to take on the maintenance of the `venndiagram` package to extend it, just let me know. Unfortunately I have way too many packages to support to spend much time on it.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I'm extremely reluctant to take it *over* (I feel I have just about as many packages as I can cope with at the moment as well), but I'd be happy to contribute to the code.  Is it available in a public repository?

Comment: @LoopSpace Not at the moment. It's currently in a local subversion repository, but I can add it to github and make you a contributor.

Comment: @Loop Space I know I already thanked you a few times :) but thanks again. It worked for me and I really do appreciate all the input, help and effort. I certainly could not have come up myself with the solution you gave us!

Comment: @NicolaTalbot That would be fine by me.

Comment: @Manuel Happy to help.  I do draw the odd venn diagram myself so I'm also helping a future version of myself!

Answer (score 6):

Something like this (it's just a rough proposition):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
   \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
%\usepackage{venndiagram}
%
\begin{document}
%\begin{venndiagram2sets}[shade=orange,tikzoptions={red}]
%   \fillA
%\end{venndiagram2sets}
\begin{tikzpicture}[red,every node/.style={font=\Large}]
    \draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,0) circle(1.5);
    \draw (2,0) circle(1.5);
        \node[fill=white,inner sep=1pt,rounded corners,below=3] at (90:1.5) {$A$};
        \node[xshift=2cm,below=3] at (90:1.5) {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT:** Here is a proposal with horizontal lines (manually pattern drawn – just for fun):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
   \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
%\usepackage{venndiagram}
%
\begin{document}
%\begin{venndiagram2sets}[shade=orange,tikzoptions={red}]
%   \fillA
%\end{venndiagram2sets}
\begin{tikzpicture}[red,every node/.style={font=\Large}]
\begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0) circle(1.5);
    \foreach \x in {-5,-4.95,...,6}
    {
        \draw[black,yshift=\x cm] (-5,\x) -- (5,\x);
    }
\end{scope}
    \draw (2,0) circle(1.5);
    \draw (0,0) circle(1.5);
        \node[fill=white,inner sep=1pt,rounded corners,below=3] at (90:1.5) {$A$};
        \node[xshift=2cm,below=3] at (90:1.5) {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your effort (nice Tikz skills!). Im not sure if Im going this route though, since this would imply that I lose most functionality of the venn diagramm package. I'll see... In any case, thanks again.