# venndiagram2sets package does not allow pattern in fillACapB

Tags: venn-diagrams

I am using the package venndiagram2sets and I was able to use patterns for most cases:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{venndiagram}

\begin{document}


\begin{venndiagram2sets}
    [tikzoptions={scale=.7, thick},labelNotAB={},labelA={},labelB={},shade={}, showframe=False]
    \begin{scope}[every path/.append style={pattern=north east lines}]
        \fillA
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[every path/.append style={pattern=north west lines}]
            \fillB
        \end{scope}
    \draw (0,2.7) node {{A}};
    \draw (5,2.7) node {{B}};
    \draw (2.5,0) node {{AB}};
\end{venndiagram2sets}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}
    [tikzoptions={scale=.7, thick},labelNotAB={},labelA={},labelB={},shade={}, showframe=False]
    \begin{scope}[every path/.append style={pattern=north east lines}]
        \fillANotB
    \end{scope}
    \draw (0,2.7) node {{A}};
    \draw (5,2.7) node {{B}};
    \draw (2.5,0) node {{AB}};

\end{venndiagram2sets}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}
    [tikzoptions={scale=.7, thick},labelNotAB={},labelA={},labelB={},shade={}, showframe=False]
    \begin{scope}[every path/.append style={pattern=north west lines}]
        \fillBNotA
    \end{scope}
    \draw (0,2.7) node {{A}};
    \draw (5,2.7) node {{B}};
    \draw (2.5,0) node {{AB}};

\end{venndiagram2sets}
% \begin{venndiagram2sets}
%   [tikzoptions={scale=.7, thick},labelNotAB={},labelA={},labelB={},shade={}, showframe=False]
%   \begin{scope}[every path/.append style={pattern=north east lines}]
%   \fillACapB
% \end{scope}
% \draw (0,2.7) node {{A}};
% \draw (5,2.7) node {{B}};
% \draw (2.5,0) node {{AB}};

% \end{venndiagram2sets}

\end{document}
```

But it does not work for the last case:

```
\begin{venndiagram2sets}
    [tikzoptions={scale=.7, thick},labelNotAB={},labelA={},labelB={},shade={}, showframe=False]
    \begin{scope}[every path/.append style={pattern=crosshatched}]
        \fillACapB
    \end{scope}
    \draw (2.5,0) node {{AB}};
  \end{venndiagram2sets}
```

Error:

```
! Package tikz Error: Extra options not allowed for clipping path command..

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.700       \fillACapB
```

How can I add a crosshatched pattern to the intersection in venndiagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a first step without a label following the code of a previous question...

[Venn Diagrams and Patterns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446941/venn-diagrams-and-patterns)

You can see that `\ofillACapB` work. I leave to you to put a nice lable using `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}` out the enviroment `{venndiagram2sets}`. At the end you can use in math mode `$\scriptstyle a=B$` instead of `\tiny` typical in text mode.

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{venndiagram,tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\newcommand*\wrapscope[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname o#1\endcsname[1][]{%
    \begin{scope}[##1]
    \csname #1\endcsname
    \end{scope}
  }%
}%

\wrapscope{fillA}
\wrapscope{fillACapB}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  clip/.append code={%
    \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty
    \tikz@addmode\tikz@mode@fillfalse%
    \tikz@addmode\tikz@mode@drawfalse%
    \tikz@addmode\tikz@mode@doublefalse%
    \tikz@addmode\tikz@mode@boundaryfalse%
    \tikz@addmode\tikz@mode@fade@pathfalse%
    \tikz@addmode\tikz@mode@fade@scopefalse%
  }
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=.7, thick},labelNotAB={},labelA={},labelB={},shade={}, showframe=False]
    \begin{scope}[every path/.append style={pattern=north east lines}]
        \ofillACapB
    \end{scope}
  \end{venndiagram2sets}

\end{document}
```

[image]